# Converting "ascii hex string of a bitmap image" into an actual image?

Tags: javascript, php, bitmap, hex, fingerprint

Working with a Topaz Systems fingerprint reader. It's... Interesting to say the least. Here is what the documentation says:

> GetBmpString() - returns ascii hex string of bmp fingerprint--useful for web applications to send fingerprint image across
>   the web

And here is what that actually returns: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d201533b07f53c07c2c (too long to paste)

Problem being, I have absolutely no idea what format that is, or how to save it as a bitmap image. I can accomplish this either locally with JS, or server-side with PHP.

Comment: Is that the entire returned data? If my analysis is correct, there should be a lot more of it.

Comment: Depends how small the image is.  Looks like a lot of white pixels.  It looks like a bitmap with extra header data in it.  I've been looking at it for a couple minutes but not sure yet.

Comment: Yes, that's the entire returned data. It seemed small to me too, but the (expected) image is only 500x500px and contains mostly whitespace.

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have stupidly truncated a bunch of the data. Here is an updated gist that contains the full response. Question still stands.. I'm not sure how to handle this.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d201533b07f53c07c2c

Comment: Ha, seems even stranger.  Have you tried the GetBitmapBufferBytes() method instead?  That might at the very least shed some light on what we're supposed to be dealing with.

Comment: I did. After some debugging (turns out it's `GetBmpBufferBytes()` not `GetBitmapBufferBytes()` as the documentation says), that function alternates between not returning anything and occasionally crashing IE.

Comment: Hmm, well, you got me.  That hex actually spells out the word image in it's header: “²...¸......äÖœ‚....i.m.a.g.e.   Which I doubt is a coincidence.  A little later, it also has "42 4D" in hex, or BM in ascii, which usually signifies the beginning of a bitmap file.  I tried editing it down to start there but with no luck.  And no image file header I found matched what you get here, so.....no idea.  Surely their support staff could help.  Also saw there's a CreateJpg method that takes a file path to save to...

Comment: Thanks for your help, Rob. I have an email in with their support staff, so hopefully that leads somewhere. I've played with CreateJpg, and that works surprisingly well, but that still leaves me with no way to actually retrieve the image in-browser and send it off to the server for processing without prompting the user to upload a file. Trying to make this as seamless as possible.